# Cannot Compile FFMPEG with libfreetype on Windows/Msys2

Tags: ffmpeg, msys2

I am having issues compiling ffmpeg with libfreetype with this commmand on windows MSYS2:

```
./configure     --pkg-config-flags="--static" --enable-libvpl  --enable-libopenh264     --enable-version3  --enable-libfreetype    --enable-libopus     --enable-libvpx     --enable-libvorbis     --enable-libaom     --enable-libdav1d     --disable-gpl     --disable-w32threads     --enable-pthreads     --disable-shared     --enable-static     --extra-cflags='--static'   --extra-cflags="-I/mingw64/include -static"   --extra-ldflags="-L/mingw64/lib -static" --prefix="/home/compiled"
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: freetype2 not found using pkg-config

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.libera.chat.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

I've installed freetype with this command:

```
 pacman -Ss mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype
```

I've also tried compiling freetype2 from the source:

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/freetype/freetype2.git

cd freetype2

mkdir build && cd build

/mingw64/bin/cmake .. -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/mingw64

make

make install
```

And pkg-config gives this:

```
pkg-config freetype2 --cflags --libs
-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16 -lfreetype
```

I can confirm the package is there:

```
ls /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc
/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc
```

Is there anything else I should be doing to compile a static version of ffmpeg with this package?

Comment: What MSYS2 environment are you running (as indicated by the magenta text in the terminal prompt)? You know you can install prebuilt ffmpeg from pacman?